# How to I keep forms from handling hotkeys when they don't have the focus?

Tags: forms, delphi, hotkeys

We have a Delphi XE2 application. `Form1` has hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, and `Form2`, which is active, without hotkeys. The user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on `Form2` and `Form1` processes the hotkey. It's totally incorrect because we see activity of the inactive form. How do I fix it?

Comment: Form1 is the MainForm right? Thats the point

Comment: You've got two modeless forms right? That's how Windows Keyboard Accelerators are meant to work.

Comment: Form1 and Form2 are not the main form.

Comment: I just want hotkeys to work only on active form. Our customers - too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I implement all short cut key handling using actions. If you do this then you can use the centralisation that actions, action lists, action managers etc. provide to enable and disable all actions based on whether or not a form is active.

Do that, for example, by setting the action list's `State` property on the `OnActivate` and `OnDeactivate` event handlers of the form:

```
procedure TMyForm.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ActionList.State := asNormal;
end;

procedure TMyForm.FormDeactivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ActionList.State := asSuspended;
end;
```

Comment: This does not work well if you have other forms inside your MyForm. Then MyForm may get deactivated while it still has the focus.

Comment: So I would rather recommend a WM_ACTIVATE handler with:
if msg.wParam = WA_INACTIVE then
        actionList.state := asSuspended 
else 
        actionList.state := asNormal;

Answer (score 2):

You could add a check for the [active form](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Forms.TScreen.ActiveForm) into the hotkey handler, ie

```
if(Screen.ActiveForm <> Self)then Exit;
```

This is assuming the eventhandler is implemented by `Form1` (which is `Self` then inside the handler).

Answer (score 0):

Just overwrite the following function of the inactive window that catches the action:

```
function IsShortCut(var Message: TWMKey): Boolean; override;

function TMainForm.IsShortCut(var Message: TWMKey): Boolean;

begin
  if MainForm.Active then
    result := inherited IsShortCut( Message )
  else
    result := false;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suspend the action lists of inactive forms you can do it on the fly in an ApplicationEventsShortCut handler as follows:

```
procedure ApplicationEventsShortCut(
              var msg     : TWMKey;
              var handled : Boolean);

    procedure SuspendInactiveFormsActionLists(
                  root : TComponent);

      var index          : integer;
      var component      : TComponent;
      var actionList     : TCustomActionList;
      var actionListForm : TCustomForm;

    begin
      for index := 0 to root.componentCount - 1 do
        begin
          component := root.components[index];

          if component is TCustomActionList then
            begin
              actionList := TCustomActionList(component);

              if actionList.owner is TCustomForm then
                begin
                  actionListForm := TCustomForm(actionList.owner);

                  if NOT actionListForm.active then
                    begin
                      actionList.state := asSuspended;
                    end;
                end;
            end
          else
            begin
              SuspendInactiveFormsActionLists(
                  component);
            end;
        end;
    end;

begin
  handled := FALSE;

  //  Make sure that the action lists of inactive forms get suspended.

  SuspendInactiveFormsActionLists(
      self);
end;
```